# Multiline Textbox that receives the lines on top

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a multiline textbox that receives values from a different class, and I want that every line is added on top instead of the bottom, how can I do that?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: You can do like this: yourTextBox.Text= "Text on top\b\r"+yourTextBox.Text

Comment: It can be done by writing code and using google search, definitely not by asking here without even trying.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Insert()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Insert(0, string.Format("{0}\r\n", "Your text content here"));
```